# kill all processes with taskkill by username but exclude some processes

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I want to kill all processes with taskkill by username, with this command:

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq %username%"
```

The problem is that I want to exclude (skip) some processes (not kill them all), such as explorer.exe, taskmgr.exe, cmd.exe, and of course current CMD instance

How can i exclude this processes with taskkill?

thanks

Comment: Hi there.  We're not a scriptwriting service, so since you've specified that you're trying to solve this with a Batch script, please include what you've attempted already, what the results were, and what's tripping you up exactly.  If this doesn't NEED to be in batch and/or using `taskkill`, please edit your question to remove the Batch tag, so you'll increase you chances of getting answers (that may or may not be Batch based). :)

Comment: the question is very clear and precise

Comment: Brian - See below in my answer for a tested and confirmed working process from what I tested and could confirm it works as expected.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows Native Batch Script CMD Method

Below is a batch script solution that uses [Tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) and [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loops setting and parsing variables accordingly to get just the process names of the processes running of a specific user.

With [Findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) these results are then parsed further to exclude any specified exclusions you set in the `Exclusions` variable up top.

It'll take the final remaining results and kill those process names for that specific username giving you the desired results via a batch script just as explained.

### Batch Script

<sup>There are only two variables to set for this to work which are the `Username` and the `Exclusions`, and the rest will just work and do the rest of the process as you need. Just specific the full process names separated by a space one next to the other just as in the below script.</sup>

```
@ECHO ON
SET Username=user
SET Exclusions=explorer.exe taskmgr.exe cmd.exe 

SET tmpfl=%temp%\%~n0tmp.dat
IF EXIST "%tmpfl%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpfl%"
SET Exclusions=%Exclusions% taskkill.exe 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME EQ %Username%" /FO LIST ^| FIND /I "Image name:"') DO (
    SET var=%%~A
    SET var=!var: =!
    ECHO !var! | FINDSTR /I /V "%Exclusions%">>"%tmpfl%"
)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %%A IN ("%tmpfl%") DO (
    TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq %Username%" /IM %%~A
)
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Batch Script 2

```
@ECHO ON
CD /D "%~DP0"
SET Exclusions=cmd.exe explorer.exe taskmgr.exe 

SET tmpfl=%~n0tmp.dat
IF EXIST "%tmpfl%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpfl%"
SET Exclusions=%Exclusions% taskkill.exe 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME EQ %Username%" /FO LIST ^| FIND /I "Image name:"') DO (
    SET var=%%~A
    SET var=!var: =!
    ECHO !var! | FINDSTR /I /V "%Exclusions%">>"%tmpfl%"
)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %%A IN ("%tmpfl%") DO (
    TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq %Username%" /IM %%~A
)
DEL /F /Q "%tmpfl%"
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**EnableDelayedExpansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**Variable Substring**](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [**Tasklist**](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)
- [**Find**](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [**Findstr**](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [**Taskkill**](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Comment: Please check the script for errors. The system can not find the file C:\Users\user1\ AppData\Local\Temp\testtmp.dat. By the way. this variable is not viable (SET Username = user) because it must serve any account. It must be replaced by %username%

Comment: This variable (SET Username = user) not needed. Only "USERNAME EQ %username%"

Comment: Yes. And the change is only in user logged

Comment: I ran the script with administrative privileges on account and the same error (win7x64)

Comment: replace %temp% with %HOMEDRIVE%

Comment: same error. D:\>FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %A IN ("testtmp.dat") DO (TASKKILL /F /FI "USER
NAME eq user1" /IM "%~A" )
The system can not find the file testtmp.dat.

D:\>DEL /F /Q "testtmp.dat"
It could not be found D:\testtmp.dat

D:\>GOTO EOF
The system can not find the batch label specified: EOF

Comment: FIND /I "image name: ????? (or imagename). This command is very rare: 'TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME EQ %username%" /FO LIST ^| FIND /I "image name:"'

Comment: SET exclusions=cmd.exe explorer.exe taskmgr.exe taskkill.exe

Comment: the same error. sorry. batch can't find C:\folder\testtmp.dat

Comment: sorry @HomeyDClownso. I have run your script in many terminals with different versions of Windows and none works. "Not find tmp file. I appreciate your effort

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do this by using powershell.

Something like this:

```
$processes = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName -like "*USERNAME*"}
$tobeignored = @("explorer","Taskmgr","cmd")
foreach($process in $processes)
{
    if($tobeignored.Contains($process.ProcessName))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        Stop-Process $process.Id -Force
    }
}
```

I have not been able to test run this, I kinda dont wanna kill my own processes :)   Let me know if it (doesn't) work(s)

Comment: Ok tested it, and made a little change :) this does the trick. Just add the proccess names (without extention) to the array, the ones u wish to leave alone

Comment: sorry i don't know anything about powershell. I need the solutions with cmd-taskkill. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your loss :)  Powershell is a powerfull scripting tool, can do a whole lot more with it compared to cmd, all the more recent (windows) OS's  come with it by default

Comment: yes i know. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying multiple filters for `taskkill`. For example, if you want to exclude explorer.exe, add a filter for the image name *not* being equal to explorer.exe (with the `ne` operator):

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq %username%" /fi "IMAGENAME ne explorer.exe"
```